# I can get the system proxy with objective-c code, but I want to write it with c++. Could you help me to convert objective-c code to c++?

Tags: objective-c, proxy, system, nsdictionary

I'm not familiar with objective-c, so it is hard for me to understand it and convert it to c++.
The objective-c code as follows, it will get the iOS system proxy. Could you help me to convert it to c++?

```
NSDictionary *proxySettings = NSMakeCollectable([(NSDictionary *)CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() autorelease]);  
NSArray *proxies = NSMakeCollectable([(NSArray *)CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"], (CFDictionaryRef)proxySettings) autorelease]);  
NSDictionary *settings = [proxies objectAtIndex:0];  
NSLog(@"host=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyHostNameKey]);  
NSLog(@"port=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyPortNumberKey]);  
NSLog(@"type=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyTypeKey]);
```

Comment: You can access this dictionary from c++ the same as you can from c. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just use plain C Core Foundation API, i.e. `CFDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`, etc.

Comment: Our c++ code can be compiled in UNIX, WIN and MAC. Now we want to support system proxy feature in our code. For the MAC platform, I just search some Object-C code as above. Now I have to convert it to c++ and compile it with GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example you found is already using C APIs (CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings, CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL), and is then going to some additional work to convert the results to something more friendly for an Objective-C program (for example, calling NSMakeCollectable to enable Objective-C garbage collection).

It may help you to understand this if you know that the "CF*" calls are "Core Foundation" API, which is callable from C (or C++), and "NS*" things are Objective-C classes/methods. So your task is to re-cast the code using just the Core Foundation calls & datatypes. For example, CFDictionary and NSDictionary are interchangeable ("toll-free bridged", in Apple parlance), so you can handle the dictionary from a C/C++ program by using the CFDictionary API instead of NSDictionary.

To understand how this is working (instead of just asking someone else to translate it for you), you will want to research functions like:

[CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFProxySupport/Reference/reference.html)

[CFURLCreateWithString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html)

[CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFProxySupport/Reference/reference.html)

[CFDictionaryGetValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html)

You'll also need a basic understanding of [Core Foundation memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW2)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks David Gelhar. With your suggestion, I wrote out the code at last, it can work on iOS and MAC:

```
int CHTTP::GetMacProxy() {    
  CFURLRef        urlRef = NULL;
  CFDictionaryRef proxyDicRef = NULL;
  CFArrayRef      urlProxArrayRef = NULL;
  CFDictionaryRef defProxyDic = NULL;
  int             port = 0;
  CFStringRef     hostNameRef = NULL;
  CFNumberRef     portNumberRef = NULL;
  char            hostNameBuffer[200];

  urlRef = CFURLCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const UInt8*)m_URL.Deref(), m_URL.Length(), kCFStringEncodingASCII, NULL);
  if (!urlRef) goto done;

  proxyDicRef = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
  if (!proxyDicRef) goto done;

 urlProxArrayRef = CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL(urlRef, proxyDicRef);
  if (!urlProxArrayRef) goto done;

  defProxyDic = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(urlProxArrayRef, 0);
  if (!defProxyDic) goto done;

  portNumberRef = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(defProxyDic, (const void*)kCFProxyPortNumberKey);
  if (!portNumberRef) goto done;
  if (!CFNumberGetValue(portNumberRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &port)) goto done;

  hostNameRef = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(defProxyDic, (const void*)kCFProxyHostNameKey);
  if (!hostNameRef) goto done;


  if (!CFStringGetCString(hostNameRef, hostNameBuffer, 200, kCFStringEncodingASCII)) goto done;

  // Log port
  // Log hostNameBuffer.


done:
  if (hostNameRef)     {CFRelease(hostNameRef); hostNameRef = NULL;}
  if (urlProxArrayRef) {CFRelease(urlProxArrayRef); urlProxArrayRef = NULL;}
  if (proxyDicRef)     {CFRelease(proxyDicRef); proxyDicRef = NULL;}
  if (urlRef)          {CFRelease(urlRef); urlRef = NULL;}

  return 0;

}
```